# No se como copiar archivo MSI desde recursos a local

Tags: c#

he "exportado" mi app al escritorio: hago este comando en el cmd: `"Runner for Windows x64.exe" -install -edge` y da error:
hay mi codigo:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {/*
            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "-install":
                        switch (args[1])
                        {
                        case "-edge":
                                    File.Copy(Runner.Properties.Resources.edgeInstaller, "c:\\local\\temp\\msedge.exe");
                                    break;
                                }
                        break;
            }*/
            

            Console.WriteLine("Executable copied to local directory.");
            switch (args[0]) {
                case "-install":
                    switch (args[1])
                    {
                        case "-edge":
                            
                            string exeResourceName = "Runner.Properties.Resources.edge64"; // Change to your resource name
                            string localPath = "C:\\Program Files\\iNS\\iNS-Runner\\packages\\"; // Change to your desired local directory

                            // Create the local directory if it doesn't exist
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);

                            string localExePath = Path.Combine(localPath, "msedge-64-msi.exe"); // Change to your desired local executable name

                            using (Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(exeResourceName))
                            {
                                if (resourceStream != null)
                                {
                                    using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(localExePath))
                                    {
                                        resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Resource not found.");
                                }
                            }
                            Process proc = new Process();
                            proc.StartInfo.FileName= "MsiExec.exe";
                            proc.StartInfo.Arguments= "/i "+ Path.Combine(localPath, "msedge-64.msi") +" /qn";
                            proc.Start();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                    
            }
        }
```

ahí creo que todo bien, pero el problema está en que con el codigo que hay en `case "-edge":` que yo quiero que el archivo MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.msi se copie a C:\Program Files\iNS\iNS-Runner\packages\ pero con el nombre de msedge-64.msi, solo que el problema es que no se quiere copiar, y quiero que una vez copiado se abra el MsiExec con los args /i (el archivo de antes) /qn, el cual segun he leido lo que hace es que abre el msi, instala el msedge-64.msi con /i pero silent, osea, con el /qn